# How to tackle 'attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions' error in R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a renderTable output in the server of Shiny and I am trying to rename the final table with the following codes:

```
output$tubeArrival <-  renderTable({

#GET request and convert JSON to a dataframe
data <-  GET(url)
text_data <-  content(data,as = 'text')
json_data <-  fromJSON(text_data)

json_data$timeToArrive = minSec(json_data$timeToStation)
json_data$bound <-  substr(as.character(json_data$platformName),1,1)
json_data$platform <-  substrRight(as.character(json_data$platformName),1)
cleaned_data <- subset(json_data,boundDirect(json_data$bound) == input$direction) 

final_data <-  cleaned_data[c('platform','towards','timeToArrive','currentLocation')]
colnames(final_data) <- c('Plat.','To','ETA','Current Loc.')

final_data <- final_data})
```

But the following error appears:

```
Warning: Error in colnames<-: attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Very appreciate any helps!

Thanks in advance,

Tommy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What line is throwing the error?  Try [`traceback()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/traceback.html) to get the callstack, and the offending line.

Just eyeballing it, it looks like you're missing a comma between the (empty) row position and the column position.  That third-to-last line might need to change to

```
final_data <- cleaned_data[, c('platform','towards','timeToArrive','currentLocation')
```

BTW, renaming columns is a safer if you do something like this.  If there is a missing column, the error message should be better.

```
cleaned_data <- json_data %>% 
  dplyr::filter(boundDirect(.$bound) == .$direction) %>% 
  dplyr::rename_(
    'Plat.'         = 'platform',
    'To'            = 'towards',
    'ETA'           = 'timeToArrive',
    'Current Loc.'  = 'currentLocation'
  )
```